# Yammer uploaded files api page limit

Tags: yammer

I used “https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files.json" to get the yammer uploaded files, but I found that I could only get 10 pages of the files. When I accessed "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files.json?page=11", I got an error:400 Bad request. So if I want to get the older files, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded_files endpoint is not publicly documented or supported at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the files with your specified API above. 400 Bad request may be due to connection timed out or else you might given the page number which is invalid.